# Bitmap gets cut off while loading into imageview

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, android-bitmap

I have a viewpager in my application and I am trying to load bitmap from app directory file using below line of code in each page of the viewpager:

```
mResultBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

My problem is that the image view rendered on the UI is half cut. For reference I have attached a couple of screenshots that depicts how the original image is vs how does it appear on the UI.

[image: Bitmap with cut off on UI]
[image: Actual image]

Comment: please show your xml file

Comment: It is a simple imageview with width and height as match parent each

Comment: Does this happen all the time, or just randomly?

Comment: It is happening randomly while I am trying to load the image in view pager using simple line of code mentioned in the question.